Wix Setup giving error loading dll issuewhile building
I have created a wix setup project of my Visual Studio C# app. My code executed successfully, I am able to get desired output, I created a setup project in wix.
But I get this error:

Either
'Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.AssemblyDefaultWixExtensionAttribute' was not defined in the assembly or the type defined in extension 'C:\code\HardwareManager\ATCommon\bin\Debug\AnyCPU\netstandard2.0\ATCommon.dll' could not be loaded.    SetupProject    candle.exe  0

Any help regarding this is highly appreciated. Thanks

